# make Angular JS real time ajax requests less consuming

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a real time DB search with angular where I bind variable $scope.city, html :

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">City@</span>
     <input type="text" ng-model="city" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('forecastController', ['$scope','varService','$http', function($scope,varService,$http){


$scope.city = varService.city;
$scope.days = 2;
$scope.$watchGroup(['days', 'city'], function() {   

        $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='+$scope.city+'&mode=json&appid=e652a2c384655ea24f5b12d2fb84c60f&cnt='+$scope.days+'&units=metric')
    .then(function(data) { $scope.forecast = data; });

  });

}]);
```

As you can see it $http.get() data every time the $scope.city changes, but it consumes too much resources , I need a solution where it will call $http.get every 3-4 seconds after user inputs something, $timeout doesn't do the job, please help , Thank You

Comment: When you say that `$timeout` doesn't do the job, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need some custom logic. 
like when raise event the $watchGroup then it need to stop execution for some second, after that second execute your process.

below example step will help you.

```
 <div data-ng-app="app">
     <div class="col-lg-8" data-ng-controller="appctrl">
         <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">City</span>
             <input type="text" ng-model="city" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('appctrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
        $scope.city = "";
        $scope.days = 2;
        var filterTextTimeout;
        $scope.$watchGroup(['days', 'city'], function () {
            if (filterTextTimeout) $timeout.cancel(filterTextTimeout); // cancel all previous register watchGroup event
            filterTextTimeout = $timeout(function () {
                alert($scope.city); // in this place call you api for get the response
            }, 5000); // delay 
        });   
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-model-options` to specify a delay on when the model changes.  Then you can trigger a function using `ng-change` to get your forecast.

```
<input ng-model-options"{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 4000, 'blur': 0 }}" ng-change="getForecast(city)" type="text" ng-model="city" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.getForecast = function(city) { $http.blahblahblah; }
```